# Cutting point of $2$ functions

Tags: calculus

$y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\frac{\left(x-3\right)}{2}$
Cut each other in $x=9$
But if you see $\sqrt{x}=\frac{\left(x-3\right)}{2}$
$x^2-10x+9=0$
Gives us $x=1$ and $x=9$
So how do we know to deny $x=1$?
(without drawing the function of course)
Thank you.

Comment: plug in $x=1$ into the first equation and you get $y=1$; plug in $x=1$ in the second equation and you get $y=-1$. The two are not equal.

Comment: Squaring the equation might give you additional solutions. This is exactly the case here with $x = 1$. How do you know that you can deny $x=1$? Well, you can simply try out whether or not the statement holds for $x=1$. In this case it does not. Therefore $x=9$ is your solution.

Comment: Also, $x^2-10x+9=0$ gives us $x=1$ **or** $x=9$, not "and."

Comment: The equation $\sqrt x=\dfrac{x-3}2$ implies the r.h.s. is nonnegative, i.e. $x\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring results in some extra roots. In this case, if you put $x=1$ in the second equation you get $y=-1$ whereas if you put $x=1$ in the first equation you get $y=1$, and $1\ne-1$. So you neglect $x=1$.

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks to everyone for the answers

Comment: @NFLX You can see the edited answer. I made a mistake by using $x=-1$ for the explanation, that has been corrected :)